# Unwanted space before image in li::before

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n3xdk48x/3/)

I am trying to style every `<li>` item so that there is a 6x10 arrow image before each `<li>`.

The 6x10 picture has a white background and the triangle/arrow itself is transparent.

Because I need these arrows to be of different colors, the idea is to set the background color of the ::before pseudo-element so that this color is visible through the transparent part of the image.

However, the resulting ::before pseudo-element turns out to be 20px high instead of 10px. There is some unwanted space (verically) before and after the image, where I can see the background-color of the pseudo-element.

How to remove that space on top and on bottom of the image?

Here is how it looks now:

[image]

And here is the desired result:

[image]

Here is the relevant part of the CSS from the fiddle above that displays the image before the list:

```
li:not(:first-child)::before {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 6px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #00b2b5;
  vertical-align: middle;
  /* white+transparent right pointing arrow */
  content: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAYAAAAKCAYAAACXDi8zAAAAW0lEQVQIW43PPQ5AQBBA4bdRKPRKV1C7hBM4j1Oo1eJ8kicrS8iSmGpmvmR+gpsDBRNQcosQc7UDFqA+7YCEDbACbawvSFgBM9A/IGHsjf9AzUep+fLXc78e3AE6bibzAA1JJgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg== 
);
}
```

Comment: We need to see your CSS you're using to show that image. HAve you got a background colour set?

Comment: @Lee the CSS is right there in the fiddle, first line of my post. I will copy the relevant part of the CSS into the post. now.

Comment: It's a combination of the background colo rbeing used for `:before`. You need to remove that, and ideally, use something else. Why dont' you look at FontAwesome for things like this? It makes it much easier if you just want a caret for a list item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/benhull/n3xdk48x/6/

It needed...

```
font-size: 0;
```

Otherwise, the image was getting offset.

A better approach would be to use CSS triangles though: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

Comment: don't know why but it worked. Thanks a lot for the answer and the CSS triangle link.

Answer (score 1):

Use the image as background to the pseudo-element rather than the content of it.

Then you can size it using `background-size`

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
li:first-child::before {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 23px;
  height: 23px;
  background: #00b2b5;
  border-radius: 50%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  /* there will be another image here */
  content: "";
}
li:not(:first-child)::before {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 6px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #00b2b5;
  vertical-align: middle;
  content: "";
  background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAYAAAAKCAYAAACXDi8zAAAAW0lEQVQIW43PPQ5AQBBA4bdRKPRKV1C7hBM4j1Oo1eJ8kicrS8iSmGpmvmR+gpsDBRNQcosQc7UDFqA+7YCEDbACbawvSFgBM9A/IGHsjf9AzUep+fLXc78e3AE6bibzAA1JJgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg== );
  background-size: 6px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="cg-webpart1-outer-block">
  <ul>
    <li>Test test test</li>
    <li>Test test test</li>
    <li>Test test test</li>
    <li>Test test test</li>
    <li>Test test test</li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

The image is `display:inline` by default. It is treated like a character, default `vertical-align:baseline`. The complement space on top and bottom of the image is added so that the element height is >= the text height.

**To fix this problem. Change the ::before element to `display:inline-block`, set `vertical-align:middle`, and set `font-size:0`. Please refer to the 6th row of the snippet example.**

`line-height:0` does not work when the image is much small than the font size. Not sure why, but there is mystery top space. Refer to 5th row of the snippet example.

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  /* default line-height is 1.2 x font-size */
  font-family: Verdana;
}

li:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: red;
}

li:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: orange;
}

li:nth-child(1) {font-size: 10px}
li:nth-child(2) {font-size: 20px}
li:nth-child(3) {font-size: 30px}

li:nth-child(4) {
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height:60px;
}
li:nth-child(5), li:nth-child(6){
  font-size: 60px;
}

li::before {
  background: cyan;
  /* vertical-align:baseline */
  /* the base64 image is 10x20 black */
  content: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhCgAUAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAAKABQAAAIMhI+py+0Po5y02usKADs=);
}

li:nth-child(5)::before {
   display:inline-block;
   line-height:0;
   vertical-align:middle;
  content:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAYAAAAKCAYAAACXDi8zAAAAW0lEQVQIW43PPQ5AQBBA4bdRKPRKV1C7hBM4j1Oo1eJ8kicrS8iSmGpmvmR+gpsDBRNQcosQc7UDFqA+7YCEDbACbawvSFgBM9A/IGHsjf9AzUep+fLXc78e3AE6bibzAA1JJgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==);
}

/* this is the answer */
li:nth-child(6)::before {
   display:inline-block;
   font-size:0;
   vertical-align:middle;
  content:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAYAAAAKCAYAAACXDi8zAAAAW0lEQVQIW43PPQ5AQBBA4bdRKPRKV1C7hBM4j1Oo1eJ8kicrS8iSmGpmvmR+gpsDBRNQcosQc7UDFqA+7YCEDbACbawvSFgBM9A/IGHsjf9AzUep+fLXc78e3AE6bibzAA1JJgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==);
}
```

```html
<div id="outer-block">
  <ul>
    <li>1 Test test test</li>
    <li>2 Test test test</li>
    <li>3 Test test test</li>
    <li><span style="background-color:lightgreen">4</span> Test test test</li>
    <li>5 Test test</li>
    <li>6 This is Answer</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```